# Let $f: A \to B$ and let $\{D_{α} : α\in Δ\}$ Prove that $f\left( \bigcup_{α\in Δ} D_{α}\right ) = \bigcup_{α\in Δ} f( D_{α})$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, relations

So I know that I need to show that each is a subset of the other but other than that, I don't know where to start. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Start with a $y\in f(\bigcup_{\alpha\in\Delta}D_{\alpha})$. What can you say about $y$?

Comment: Then y=f(x) for some x in $\bigcup_{α\in Δ} D_{α}$

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot the $D_{α}$.

Comment: right. So now you have that $x\in D_{\alpha_0}$ for some $\alpha_{0}$ which means that $y=f(x)\in f(D_{\alpha_0})\subset\bigcup_{\alpha\in\Delta}f(D_{\alpha})$. So you have done one inclusion. Cam you try the other?

Comment: So would I start with some $x\in D_{α}$ ?

Comment: No. For the other inclusion you start with $y\in \bigcup_{\alpha\in\Delta}f(D_{\alpha})$ and use what you know about unions

Comment: Have you understood what to do or do you need a further hint?

Comment: I got it, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the fact that 
$$
A\subset B\implies f(A)\subset f(B)
$$
Since for any $\alpha$
$D_{α}\subset \bigcup_{α\in Δ} D_{α}$, there is
$$
f(D_{α})\subset f(\bigcup_{α\in Δ} D_{α})\quad\text{and so}\quad \bigcup_{α\in Δ}f(D_{α})\subset f(\bigcup_{α\in Δ} D_{α})
$$
On the other hand, for any $y\in f(\bigcup_{α\in Δ}D_{α})$, there is a $x\in \bigcup_{α\in Δ}D_{α}$ such that $y=f(x)$. So there is a $\alpha$ that $x\in D_{\alpha}$ and $y=f(x)$. Thus 
$$
y\in f(D_{α})\subset f(\bigcup_{α\in Δ} D_{α})\quad\text{and so}\quad f(\bigcup_{α\in Δ} D_{α})\subset \bigcup_{α\in Δ}f(D_{α})
$$
Thus we have
$$
f(\bigcup_{α\in Δ} D_{α})=\bigcup_{α\in Δ}f(D_{α})
$$